# SSIS Parameters

Tags: parameters, ssis

I'm creating a SSIS package - incremental loading (first time: and I'm following a video) I'm finding it dificult knowing which parameter maps to the destination columns. For example, I have around 20 columns how can I be sure that I'm mapping to the correct destination column?

How does one know which Parameter maps to which column? I hope this makes sense...

```
Update [MCS].[SironHealth].[CallLog]
set [ID_CARD] = ?,
[CALL_DATE] = ?,
[CALL_PATIENT_NUMBER] = ?,
[CALL_TYPE] = ?,
[CALL_IN_OUT] = ?,
 where [CALL_NUMBER] = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `OLE.DB` as `connection type`, that is why you are using `?` as the `parameter name` for each parameters, if doing so, you have to manually get the `parameter name` for each, for example, in your case, `parameter name` for `ID_CARD` will be 0, the next `CALL_DATE` will have 1 as `parameter name`, so the parameter name mapping will be from 0-5 for your parameters from top to down. Leave the size as `-1` as the default, do not forget to choose the correct data type. It will be little confusing if you have lots of `?`, you have to be very carefully when picking index number for each parameter.

**OR**

If you use `ADO.net` as `connection type`, you could leave the parameter as, for example `@ID_CARD`, which will be like `set [ID_CARD] = @ID_CARD`, then you could use the `@ID_CARD` as the `parameter name` directly in `parameter` page

Comment: ODBC also uses the `?` as a placeholder but that is a 1 based ordinal system

Comment: I followed my column order in the SQL Update command. So first Column = 0 and so on. As mentioned above.